# Add insert limit on many-to-many relation

Tags: php, yii, yii2

how do we add a limit to many-to-many relation. Following the example in the documentation let's say we have 3 tables `post`, `category` and `post_category`. Let's say I have a list of posts and on every post a possibility to choose a category.

How can I 'limit' the relation so that there can't be more then 5 categories per post and 100 posts per category?

I have managed to do so using a checking if `count(post->books) < 5` on the create action of `post_category` controller but am looking for a way to do it more Yii friendly, if that exists.

Working on Yii 1.1.14.

Answer (score 1):

You can using custom validation rules. For example in your PostCategory model, add the following rule

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['post'], 'validateSize'],
    ];
}
```

Then anywhere in the model add validateSize()

```
public function validateSize($attribute_name,$params){
   if(sizeof($this->post->categories) > 4)
      $this->addError($attribute_name, Yii::t('post', 'You cant have more than 5 categories per post'));
}
```

This will give an error when trying to create a new category belonging to a post that already has 4 categories

Comment: What do you mean by this: This will give an error when trying to create a new category belonging to a post that already has 4 categories? I am creating posts and categories independently. Shouldn't I add the validation rule in the PostCategory model then?

Comment: I did not see your models, but what I understood from the question is that you have a one to many relations between Post and Category. I thus deduced that you must have a field post_id or whatever in category, and not  a separate relations model. 
If you have a separate model however, PostCategory that binds the two, then you can add it there as well. Both will work, depending on where do you want to get the error, and how you use your models :)

Comment: Well, I think i wrote everything down correctly in my first question. I have a MANY-MANY relationship between Post and Category resulting in having a PostCategory table in the middle.

Comment: Then its my mistake then :)
Put it in the PostCategory model